# how to get the id of a checkbox in a GridView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a checkbox and appears on each line of the GridView and I want to find the id of the checkbox that has been ticked.

Code for GridView:

```
<asp:GridView  style="width:75%"  
                        ID="gvCVRTDetails" 
                        ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"
                        CssClass="tblResults" 
                        runat="server" 
                        OnRowDataBound="gvCVRTDetails_RowDataBound"                             
                        DataKeyField="ID" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                        allowpaging="false"
                        AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="tblResultsHeader" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Checklist Items"></asp:BoundField> 
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Checked?" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                         <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChecked" runat="server" onchange=UpdateCheckedBox(this,this.value)></asp:CheckBox>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

I tried using `onchange=UpdateCheckedBox(this,this.value)` and `onchange=UpdateCheckedBox(this.id,this.checked)` but it doesn't return the id.

I added a simple function so I can check the id of the checkbox:

```
function UpdateCheckedBox(id, checked) {
        alert(id);
        alert(checked);
    }
```

If I use `this.id` the alert message is blank. If I use `this` is says [object htmlSpanElement]. Using `this.checked` or `this.value` just returns undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function UpdateCheckedBox(e) {
    alert(e.checked);
}
```

and checkbox change control should be call as below:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkChecked" runat="server" onclick=UpdateCheckedBox(this)></asp:CheckBox>
```

Comment: Alert still says undefined

Comment: Sorry, change onchange to onclick.

Comment: thanks but the alert just says "on". I need to find the id of the checkbox

Comment: e.id will retun you control id.

Comment: is there a way to return the id from the database? Each checkbox has its own id but the id being returned here is the id created by the code

Comment: <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChecked" runat="server" onclick="UpdateCheckedBox(this)" data-id="<%#Eval("ID-Field")%>"></asp:CheckBox>

and then use jquery to retrieve attribute value of this. e.g $(e).attr("data-id")

Comment: I get the error The server tag is not well formed.. <asp:CheckBox ID="chkChecked" runat="server" onclick="UpdateCheckedBox(this)" data-id="<%#Eval("ID")%>" ></asp:CheckBox>

Comment: data-id='<%#Eval("ID")%>'

Use single quote